# Socket components TcpClient can use http proxy?

Tags: c#, http, proxy, network-programming, tcpclient

The TcpClient access site content, can use an HTTP proxy? Or use socket5 agents it?If you can, then, how to do?

Comment: You are using HTTP protocol! Do what Jonathon says please

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use the [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) class instead of doing it manually with a `TcpClient`?

It allows you to set a [`Proxy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.proxy.aspx).

Comment: Glad I could help - welcome to StackOverflow. Remember to accept an answer if it takes care of your problem.